# Disable auto-trimming of text by <p> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have some text in a var. `var text = " Hell O "` . each character of the text is wrapped in span tag , given an id and then appended to innerhtml of a p tag. Then with a function  each span is styled (on an event).

Problem is that any spaces at the beginning or end of the p tag are not getting highlighted. I am not sure whether the p tag is ignoring the spaces and not including them in the final para . But it does seem that the first/last spaces are not being included.

This is my styling function btw.

```
function highlightLetter(typedletter) {
        var targetId = "h"+( typedletter );
        makeGreen = document.getElementById(targetId) ;
        if (makeGreen) {
            console.log(makeGreen.innerText.charCodeAt(0)) ;
            if (makeGreen.innerText.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(10)) == -1 ) {
                makeGreen.style.background  = "lightgreen" ;
            }

        }
    }
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Please post all the relevant code, minimally either with the code that adds tags to the data or the resulting HTML code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whitespace at the beginning and end of a paragraph isn't rendered. Also, sequences of whitespace within the paragraph are collapsed.

If you want all your whitespace to be rendered use [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) entity`&nbsp;`. Note that this will affect line breaking and may induce horizontal scroll where lines would otherwise be wrapped.

You can replace all ordinary whitespace characters with non-breaking space like this:

```
var text = " Hell O ";
text.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;");
```

Alternatively, you can also use `<pre>...</pre>` tags.

Comment: I can't use the pre tag. div tag also doesn't render whitespace at the end. Any other tag that can be used to render whitespace at the end? including from html5