# why white space are getting ignored in AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> AngularJS application:

The ng-model directives bind the input fields to the controller properties.In my application the inputs with spaces are ignored, for example : `"  A"`,the resulting output is `"A"`.

Is there a way to include those white spaces as well ?

[image]

Fiddled [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pa6sdudd/2/)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the `ng-trim="false"` attribute to [stop Angular from trimming the extra whitespace in input fields](http://www.gregpike.net/2012/11/javascript/disable-angularjs-from-automatically-trimming-inputs/).

---

Besides that, you also have the additional problem that the [whitespace isn't rendered in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9046185/2539335).

You can fix this for example by using

```
Full Name: <pre>{{Location + " " + Item}}</pre>
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pa6sdudd/6/)

Or alternatively by using css:

```
white-space: pre;
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pa6sdudd/7/)

Comment: Does that have any advantage over other solution?need an apt solution for thesame..thanks @Dark Ashelin

Comment: @utility You need both solutions to make it work. As you can see in the Vision's demo he also used `<pre>`, he just didn't explain it.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`ng-trim="false"`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D) directive:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Location" ng-trim="false">
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pa6sdudd/4/